# Conditionally clear content of cells subject to Data>Validity

Tags: macros, formula, validation, libreoffice-calc

In CALC I have a column which I set up to be filled with values from a specified cell range (using `Data > Validity` menu). This column represent a "Forecast date" in a spreadsheet used as a TODO list. Now another column in this sheet represent the effective date when an item is done.

I would like that, when this "Done Date" column is filled in a row, then the corresponding value in the "Forecast date" disappears. I thought it would be straightforward to put in the Forecast date column a formula `IF(ISBLANK())` but I can't have in this column a formula AND a `Data>Validity`: if I choose an item in the list the formula is cleared, etc. Is there a way to do so?

**Edit:**

Screenshot as requested. Column A is where user selects a date within the list, and I want to remove that date if something is filled in Column B.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Would it be ok if the cell isn't cleared (value removed) but if the value "disappears" by using conditional formatting (same foreground / background color)?

Comment: Didnt thought about conditionnal formatting. I guess it could be ok, although if there exists a proper way to clear the cell content I would like to know it aswell.

Comment: You could trigger a macro to delete the entry in Column A - if i find some time, i will have a look at it.